# AttributeError: module 'tweepy' has no attribute 'OAuthHandler' ImportError: No module named 'tweepy.auth'

Tags: python, oauth, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth, tweepy

```
enter code here 
import queue
import time
import tweepy
import re

consumer_key = 'c65mUHOn31bv4bw7ZqyAvsZLv'
consumer_secret = 'umxOyBGSkTNSnZW308wnh4m2AVmIlXgxUteAJL06riPteXqz5X'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
```

+code

I GET THIS ERROR when runnig

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "luckyBot.py", line 31, in <module>
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
AttributeError: module 'tweepy' has no attribute 'OAuthHandler'
```

#

i have also tried:

```
from tweepy.auth import OAuthHandler
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
```

but that make me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "luckyBot.py", line 7, in <module>
    from tweepy.auth import OAuthHandler
ImportError: No module named 'tweepy.auth'
```